# VBA how to insert a variable into this command: Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "show.toolbar(""Ribbon"",True)"

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to hide the toolbar of my excel workbook based on the value of cell B60 which can be either True or False. How can I replace the True in this formula with a variable which contains a cell value?

```
Sub AdjustSheets()

Dim status_bar As String
status_bar = Range("B59").Value
'Note value in B59 is either True or False

'This hides Menu, how do I replace the "True" with a variable containing a cell reference?'
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "show.toolbar(""Ribbon"",True)"

'This hides Status bar, here I am able to use a variable to replace True or False'
Application.DisplayStatusBar = status_bar

End Sub
```

Comment: `Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "show.toolbar(""Ribbon""," & status_bar & ")"`

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, but this is not working for me.

Comment: Tested and works for me. Note that your description says B60 but your code says B59. Or, what does `Debug.Print status_bar` return in the Immediate Window?

Comment: It should work as suggested above. `True` is a `String` in this context and it should work if the appropriate cell has been used.

Comment: @BigBen just tried again, it is working now thank you so much . The Debug.Print was just to print the cell reference in the "immediate window" in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

To escape variables in VBA you do the following:

```
" & some_variable & "
```

Answer (score 0):

@BigBen provided me with the answer

```
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "show.toolbar(""Ribbon""," & status_bar & ")"
```